# What's the best way to terminate a program on error?

Tags: java

What would you say is the best way to shut down a program after catching an exception and taking care of it in the main function?

1. return
2. System.exit(...)
3. re-throw the exception
4. throw a custom exception as a wrapper
5. throw a runtime exception
6. something else

   ```
   public static List<String> readFile(String file)
           throws NoSuchFileException, EOFException, IOException {
       Path p = Paths.get(file);
       if (!Files.exists(p)) {
           throw new NoSuchFileException(file);
       } else if (!Files.isRegularFile(p)) {
           throw new NoRegularFileException(file);
       } else if (!Files.isReadable(p)) {
           throw new AccessDeniedException(file);
       } else if (Files.size(p) == 0) {
           throw new EOFException(file);
       }
       return Files.readAllLines(p);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           if (args.length != 2) {
               System.out.println("The proper use is: java MyProgram file1.txt file2.txt");
               return;
           }

           List<List<String>> files = new ArrayList<>();
           for (String s : args) {
               try {
                   files.add(Utilities.readFile(s));
               } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
                   System.out.printf("File %s does not exist%n", e.getMessage());
                   System.exit(-1);
               } catch (NoRegularFileException e) {
                   System.out.printf("File %s is not a regular file%n", e.getMessage());
                   throw e;
               } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
                   System.out.printf(
                       "Access rights are insufficient to read file %s%n", e.getMessage()
                   );
                   throw new ReadFileException(e);
               } catch (EOFException e) {
                   System.out.printf("File %s is empty%n", e.getMessage());
                   throw new RuntimeException(e);
               }
           }
           //some other code
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```

Edit: I should have made it clear that there would be some other code in the program before the end of main, so I can't just let it finish.

Comment: That depends on how you define "best".

Comment: If the catch is the last part of the main method, the catch executes, the main would end anyway. If you wanna do error reporting, you can always log in the catch block.

Comment: I suggest that you'd better *log* the exception instead of just throw it or print an error message. Also, you should use the `Error Stream` when printing error messages (`System.err.println("Your message");`). Apart from these, exiting the program with `System.exit(1);` should do the work.

Comment: @Kayaman Here that would be in a way that does not look weird. The result is always the same anyway, but I was wondering if some of my options were improperly used.

Comment: Return from any method; Exit only from your `main` method. Log any exceptions. Handle the code in case a `catch` block is activated and not just print an error message.

Comment: Create a custom exception and throw it to the main block if you wanna exit the main program. Rest exceptions can be catched and dealt with in the logic but with no program termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be clean (i.e. not display stacktrace to user), then throwing exceptions is out of the question (at least out of main). Then it's all about whether you want to return an exit code from the program if not.

If you want to return the exit code, you have to use `System.exit(int errcode);`. Otherwise you can just return (or let `main` exit normally).

Comment: Return it is then.